# rbind two datatables and make a new column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, rbind

Hi i have two datasets which represent to different groups:

```
student_details <- c("John", "Henrick", "Maria", "Lucas", "Ali")
student_class <- c("High School", "College", "Preschool", "High School", "college")
df1 <- data.frame(student_details, student_class)
```

#another dataframe

```
Student_details<-c("Bracy","Evin")
Student_class<-c("High school","College")
Student_rank<-c("A","A+")
df2<-data.frame(Student_class,Student_details,Student_rank)

df2
```

I need to rbind df1 and df2 even though the lenght is unequal and make a third column in the final called "dataset" which indicates which dataset it is from:

Comment: Please add an expected output. I think you want `cbind`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `rbindlist()` function from the `data.table` package to accomplish this.

It is important that the column names are the same in both dataframes, as you want to bind by column name.

```
#convert uppercase letters in column names to lower case. 
names(df2) <- tolower(names(df2))
```

Next, bind them together:

```
library(data.table)
final_df <- rbindlist(list(df1, df2), use.names = T, fill = T, idcol = "dataset")
final_df
```

Output:

```
   dataset student_details student_class student_rank
1:       1            John   High School         <NA>
2:       1         Henrick       College         <NA>
3:       1           Maria     Preschool         <NA>
4:       1           Lucas   High School         <NA>
5:       1             Ali       college         <NA>
6:       2           Bracy   High school            A
7:       2            Evin       College           A+
```

Comment: nice way of using `rbindlist`, solve the problem in an easy way, +1!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your column name student_details,student_class is same across data frame. You can use bind_rows which is more flexible than rbind.
It will create NA values.

```
student_details <- c("John", "Henrick", "Maria", "Lucas", "Ali")
student_class <- c("High School", "College", "Preschool", "High School", "college")
df1 <- data.frame(student_details, student_class)


student_details<-c("Bracy","Evin")
student_class<-c("High school","College")
student_rank<-c("A","A+")
df2<-data.frame(student_details,student_class,student_rank)

library(dplyr)

df_full<-bind_rows(df1,df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

With your specific `df1` and `df2`, we can try `merge` from base R

```
> merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
  student_details student_class student_rank
1            John   High School         <NA>
2         Henrick       College         <NA>
3           Maria     Preschool         <NA>
4           Lucas   High School         <NA>
5             Ali       college         <NA>
6           Bracy   High school            A
7            Evin       College           A+
```

but the `data.table` option using `rbindlist` should work in general sense (see answer by [@Flap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74532994/12158757))